# How can I use the started session in php in an android application

Tags: android, session

I wrote a login system in android and my android code for request to the `php` is like this [link](http://androidexample.com/How_To_Make_HTTP_POST_Request_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=64&aaid=89). Also my login code in `php` is as follows:

```
<?php
start_session();
if(isset($_SESSION['login_user'])) 
{
echo "You are logged in";
}
else {
//check the username and password fields and if they are correct and they are 
//available So create the following session variable;
$_SESSION['login_user'] = $username;
}
?>
```

And then I install my program in my device and I run it. And then I fill the username and password fields and then I send them to the serer.Now my server checks them and because they are correct as the result it does the  `$_SESSION['login_user'] = $username;` statements. Now I should have a session in server (Also I have a local server in my device).

I can create the session variable in server successfully and when I fill the fields again, I should see the `You are logged in` message, because I created a session variable successfully already. Now I do not fill one of the fields and I click on the submit button and because I have the `$_SESSION['login_user']` still I should see the  `You are logged in` message again. But I see the message that it says for me one of the fields is empty.

As the result it seems I have no session variable still. when I tested my `php` code in `wampserver` in windows I could create the `$_SESSION['login_user'] = $username;` and when I do not fill one of the fields and I submit the form to the `php` file, I can see the `You are logged in` message because I have the session still. as the result it seems that my android code is incomplete. my android code is like this [link](http://androidexample.com/How_To_Make_HTTP_POST_Request_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=64&aaid=89).

Comment: What is the exact "message that it says for me one of the fields is empty" that you're getting? Are you using any kind of CookieManager on your Android code (to save the cookie you're getting from the server and send it on your next requests)?

Comment: Thank you. I do not use the `CookieManager` in my code. How can I should use it in my code to solve this problem? My code is like the link in my post.

Comment: I can only point you to the manual that explains it: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html